# How to subscribe to elements in a response object

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I am currently subscribed to a service endpoint and console logging the object response.

**The Response**

[image]

I am trying to map to the response value zoneName and zoneName within the 1st and 2nd zones array.
Whenever I map to this response I receive an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

How can I take this value and set it within a variable without getting this error?

**Ts file**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private zoneService: ZoneService){}

ngOnInit() {
this.zoneService.getAllZonesWithCounts().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    console.log(res);
    // let zoneName = res[0].map((res) => res.zoneName);
    // let zoneNames = [];
    // res.forEach()
    // console.log(zoneName);
});


var chart = new Chart("myChart", {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: "bar",

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Zone Counts By Asset Type",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
      },
    ],
  },
  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
[
{
    "zoneId": 1,
    "zoneName": "",
    "ord": 0,
    "zones": [
        {
            "zoneId": 2,
            "zoneName": "",
            "ord": 0,
            "zones": [
                {
                    "zoneId": 3,
                    "zoneName": "",
                    "parentZoneId": 2,
                    "assetCount": 65,
                    "ord": 0,
                    "zones": [],
                    "typeCounts": [
                        {
                            "id": "1:",
                            "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
                            "count": 65
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "zoneId": 4,
                    "zoneName": "",
                    "parentZoneId": 2,
                    "assetCount": 0,
                    
                    },
                    
                    "ord": 0,
                    "zones": [],
                    "typeCounts": [
                        {
                            "id": "1:",
                            "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
                            "count": 0
                        }
                    ]
                {
                    "zoneId": 5,
                    "zoneName": "",
                    "assetCount": 0,
                    "ord": 0,
                    "zones": [],
                    "typeCounts": [
                        {
                            "id": "1:",
                            "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
                            "count": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "zoneId": 6,
                    "zoneName": "",
                    "parentZoneId": 2,
                    "assetCount": 0,
                    "ord": 0,
                    "zones": [],
                    "typeCounts": [
                        {
                            "id": "1:",
                            "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
                            "count": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeCounts": [
                {
                    "id": "1:",
                    "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
                    "count": 65
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "typeCounts": [
        {
            "id": "1:",
            "typeName": "Infusion Pump",
            "count": 65
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: your res an array of objects, so `res['']` will be undefined. you need to access your first element like `res[0]`

Comment: @rhavelka using `res[0]` returns this error `TypeError: res[0].map is not a function`

Comment: try `res.map()`

Comment: @rhavelka `res.map()` returns an error of `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.` before compilation

Answer (score 0):

so if your response is an array containing one object, you should do something like
`res[0].zones.map((res) => res.zoneName)`
to get the names of the zones.

However if your response is an array of objects (containing more than one) then you should also loop on it. E.g:

```
let zoneNames = []
res.forEach(entry => {
   const zoneNamesTemp = entry.zones.map(zone => zone.zoneName)
   zoneNames = [...zoneNames, ...zoneNamesTemp]
})
```

Comment: thanks for sharing an answer. Whenever I try to use `forEach()` on my res object I receive an error `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Object'` similarly to @rhavelka 's response

Comment: okay so your res is not an array! its an object.. can you provide the value of res? what is the output of console.log(res)?

Comment: response is image above, is that feasible for you?

Comment: image suggests that it is an array, however it seems that its an object... do a console.log(res) and provide the output

Comment: I console logged as `console.log("Response" + res);`, I received an output of type object `Reponse[object Object]`

Comment: @Peter this is where I was getting confused too. The response is expecting a type of object but res is actually an array. maybe try `.subscribe((res: any[]) => {})` to get the correct typing

Comment: Not sure what is going on.. just do a console.log(res) and lets see the output!! Nothing else; no string concat.just res

Comment: I've done both there. `console.log(res)` returns the screenshot that I have reuploaded above. When I hover over the root of the response in the browser it says it's an object

Comment: Is it enlosed in {} or []? Can u confirm if its an array or object?

Comment: It looks to be an object {} enclosed within an array []. Would sharing my api or service help at all?

Comment: Sharing of the data would be helpful. Maybe paste the response (u can remove the data that are sensitive ofc). Whats the result if u do console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) ?

Comment: @Peter I tried JSON.stringify(res) I have attached the output above. You can see the object is within an array

Comment: So if u do res[0] u will have the object thus the res[0].zones.map((res) => res.zoneName) should be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229745/discussion-between-peter-and-alex).